# double insert in database while submiting form using Ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to submit my form with ajax.

So I'm using the following ajax code:

```js
<script>
    if ($("#castingform").length > 0) {
        $("#castingform").validate({
             rules: {
                 casting_name: {
                     required: true,
                     maxlength: 50
                 },
                  casting_photo: {
                     required: true
                 },
             },
             messages: {
                casting_name: {
                  required: "Please enter name",
                  maxlength: "Name should be 50 characters long."
                },
              casting_photo: {
                  required: "Please enter photo"
                },
             },
             submitHandler: function(form) {
                 $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                 });

                 $('#castingform').on('submit', function(event) {
                     event.preventDefault();
                     $.ajax({
                         url:"{{ url('castings') }}",
                         method:"POST",
                         data:new FormData(this),
                         dataType:'JSON',
                         contentType: false,
                         cache: false,
                         processData: false,
                         success:function(res) {
                            $("#createBtn").removeClass("disabled");
                            $("#createBtn").text("Sign in");

                            if (res.status == "success") {
                              $(".result").html("<div class='alert alert-success rounded'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>" + res.message+ "</div>");
                              /* location.reload();*/
                            } else if(res.status == "failed") {
                              $(".result").html("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>" + res.message+ "</div>");
                            }
                         }
                     });
                 });
             }
        })
    }
</script>
```

But when I click for the first time on the button submit, the success message doesn't show, and for the second time I get the success message but I find a double insert in the database.

My Controller

**EDIT**

```js
public function store(Request $request)
{
      
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'casting_name' => 'required',
        'casting_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
    
     if ($validator->passes()) {
         $input['casting_photo'] = time().'.'.$request->casting_photo->extension();
         $request->casting_photo->move(public_path('castingimages'), $input['casting_photo']);
         $data = [
             'casting_name' => $request->casting_name,  
             'casting_photo'=> $input['casting_photo']
         ];
       
         Casting::create($data);
       
         return response()->json([
             "status" => "success", 
             "message" => "Success! post created."
         ]);
     }
         
     return response()->json([
         "status" => "failed", 
         "message" => "Alert! post not created"
     ]);
}
```

I think the problem is in this line `submitHandler: function(form)` and this line `$('#castingform').on('submit', function(event) {`, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: check your controller, probably you added 2 create/save method

Comment: Can you share `castings` method to check how you have implemented it.

Comment: can you please share controller method code?

Comment: You are missing `error` method so at first you are not getting error message. Add it as shown in [this image](https://dropover.cloud/cdfe67) and can you share the log.